# Creating azure throttling exception

Tags: exception

How can we create a throttling exception easily, in a cost effective manner, in sql azure? This is to test the TransientFaultHandling libraries in windows azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way! create a mock class derived from ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy and return true. Use this class in 
          `var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<MockClass>(retryStrategy);` 
That is it! No need to create a genuine throttling exception. [for more..](http://azuretable.blogspot.nl/2012/08/unit-testing-transient-errors-in-azure.html)